# I can´t import bean definitions from relative location

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting the next error when I import `context-cfg.xml` in `applicationContext.xml`.

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: 
Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/context-cfg.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from 
class path resource [context-cfg.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path 
resource [context-cfg.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

aplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


<import resource="classpath:/context-cfg.xml" /> //this line throws the error

</beans>
```

The structure of my project is as follows

[image]

Can any one help me?

Comment: To make your file in the classpath you need to place it at the java ressource directory or change the line like that : <import resource="classpath:/resources/context-cfg.xml" />

Comment: @AyoubMk, I tried that and I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation of Maven : [Maven project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

> Within artifact producing source directories (ie. main and test), there is one directory for the language java (under which the normal package hierarchy exists), and one for resources (the structure which is copied to the target classpath given the default resource definition).

So you have two options :

**Option 1 :**

change the location of your file to Java resources

**Option 2 :**

change statement like this `<import resource="classpath:/resources/context-cfg.xml" />` 
In this case, your code will work fine in eclipse env, but during your maven build you need to add the resource folder to your classpath

Comment: Thank you!!  I have read the doc and I've decide to option 1